# Why are all dependencies forced in Homebrew FFmpeg 4.1?

Tags: macos, homebrew, open-source

When upgrading to the latest FFmpeg (4.1) through Homebrew, I noticed that an overwhelming number of new dependencies were installed. At the same time, `brew info ffmpeg` revealed that all installation options were gone. So someone decided that there is only one FFmpeg, then. All or nothing. Where can I find information about this decision and the reason for doing so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Issue 31510: Remove all options

See [Remove all options from Homebrew/homebrew-core formulae #31510](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/31510):

> Options in formulae don't produce a good user experience because they have to be built from source, we don't test them in CI and each combination of options provides a new chance for new failures to occur. We should seek to (eventually!) remove all options from formulae in Homebrew/homebrew-core in favour of enabling as much non-exclusive functionality as possible in a given formula for widely used options or encouraging the community to maintain their own custom options in a tap (e.g. https://github.com/denji/homebrew-nginx/blob/master/Formula/nginx-full.rb). As an absolute last resort if we need to depend on the same formula multiple times with different options (e.g. #13133) we can consider vendoring formulae using `resource` blocks or even duplicating formulae.

You can explore the history of the [ffmpeg formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commits/master/Formula/ffmpeg.rb) to see other changes to the dependencies and options.

Comment: Ah! So it's not only FFmpeg. Well, as much as I hate a dozen dependencies falling down on me like a ton of bricks for every little utility I want to check out, now I don't have to endure 15 minutes of fan noise compiling FFmpeg anymore. So good news in the big picture, then. Thanks for pointing this out.